# I need some help for a keras image classifier project

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras, classification

I've been doing this imager and it does not compile. The document of training if it works well but the document to predict the image does not.

It consists of an image classifier based on these videos.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EAqb20_4Rdg&t=450s

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWz0N4FFL0U&t=53s

THIS IS THE TRAINING CODE (IT WORKS PERFECTLY)

```py
import sys                                                                         # Lo vamos a hacer con TensorFLow pero dentro de este tenemos la posibilidad de usar Keras.
import os                                                                          # Vamos a importar las librerias que nos van a permitir movernos entre los directorios de nuestro sistema.
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator         # Libreria que nos va a pre-procesar las imagenes para entrenar a nuestro algoritmo:
from tensorflow.python.keras import optimizers                                     # Importo los optimizadores:
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential                              # Importo la libreria que nos permite hacer redes neurnales secueniales (Cada una de las capas está ordenada):
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dropout, Flatten, Dense, Activation
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D             # Importo las capas en las cuales vamos a estar haciendo nuestras convoluciones y max-pooling:
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K                                   # Importo la libreria que nos va a ayudar a que si hay una sesión de queras que está corriendo en segundo plano, matarlo y empezar de 0:

K.clear_session()                                                                  # Empiezo una sesión nueva:

data_entrenamiento = r'C:\Users\JOSEA\Downloads\data\train'                           # La "r" al principio de la string la va a transformar en uns RAW string para que no detecte el comando especial "\".
data_validacion = r'C:\Users\JOSEA\Downloads\data\validation'


##Parametros:

epocas = 20                                                                        # Veces que vamos a iterar nuestro DataSet.
altura, longitud = 100, 100                                                        # Tamaño al que vamos a procesar nuestras imágenes.
batch_size = 32                                                                    # Número de imágenes que vamos a enviar para procesar en cada uno de las iteraciones. (Evitar sobrecarga de RAM).
pasos = 1000                                                                       # Número de veces que se va a procesar la información en cada una de las épocas.
pasos_validacion = 200                                                             # Al final de cada época se van a ejecutar 200 pasos con nuestro DataSet de validación (Comprobación).
filtrosConv1 = 32
filtrosConv2 = 64                                                                  # Número de filtros que va a haber en cada convolución. Profundidad de las capas ocultas.
tamano_filtro1 = (3,3)
tamano_filtro2 = (2,2)                                                             # Filtro(altura x longitud)
tamano_pool = (2,2)                                                                # Tamaño del filtro en MaxPooling
clases = 2                                                                         # "gato", "perro", "gorila"
lr = 0.0005                                                                        # Learning rate. Que tan grande va a ser el ajuste para acercarse a una solución óptima (numero pequeño)

##Pre-procesamiento de imagenes:

# Creo un generador al que le voy a indicar como preprocesar la información y después voy a hacer la transformación de las imágenenes.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

entrenamiento_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,                          # Transforma cada pixel de un RANGO de 0-255 a un rango de 0-1 (Downnscale)
    shear_range = 0.3,                         # Va a INCLINAR y rotar cada imagen para que el algoritmo aprenda como es el objeto desde todas las perspectivas
    zoom_range = 0.3,                          # Va a hacer ZOOM a cada imagen para entrenar al algoritmo de forma alterna.
    horizontal_flip = True                     # Va a INVERTIR la imagen.
)

validacion_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255                           # Solo REESCALO estas imágenes de test para comparar con los resultados de entrenamiento.
)

# Creo las dos variables que van a contener a las imágenes procesadas de Training y Testing.
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

imagen_entrenamiento = entrenamiento_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_entrenamiento,                        # Va a entrar al directorio "data".
    target_size = (altura, longitud),          # Va a preprocesar todas las imágenes que se encuentre a una altura y longitud (definidas arriba).
    batch_size = batch_size,                   # Va a tomar una cantidad de 32 imágenes para cada iteración.
    class_mode = 'categorical'                 # La clasificación va a ser categórica ["perro","gato","gorila"]
)

imagen_validacion = validacion_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    data_validacion,
    target_size = (altura, longitud),
    batch_size = batch_size,
    class_mode = 'categorical'
)

# Creo nuestra red neuronal convolucional:
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

cnn = Sequential()                                                                                                      # Le vamos a decir que la Red sea seuencial, es decir, varias capas apiladas entre ellas.

cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtrosConv1, tamano_filtro1, padding='same', input_shape=(altura, longitud,3), activation='relu')) # Convolución(Filtros, Tamaño_Filtro, Filtro_esquinas, Tamaño_Imagen, Función_de_activación=RELU).
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = tamano_pool))                                                                          # Después de la capa de Convolución vamos a tener una capa de MaxPooling que va a tener un tamaño de (2,2) pixels.

cnn.add(Convolution2D(filtrosConv2, tamano_filtro2, padding='same', activation='relu'))                                 # Convolución(Filtros, Tamaño_Filtro, Filtro_esquinas, Función_de_activación=RELU).
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = tamano_pool))                                                                          # Después de la capa de Convolución vamos a tener una capa de MaxPooling que va a tener un tamaño de (2,2) pixels.

cnn.add(Flatten())                                                                                                      # Vamos a transformar la imagen que es muy profunda y pequeña a una muy grando plana de una sola dimensión.
cnn.add(Dense(256, activation = 'relu'))                                                                                # Añade una capa de 256 neuronas donde van a estar todas las neuronas de las capas anteriores. Función de activación es relu.
cnn.add(Dropout(0.5))                                                                                                   # Le voy a "apagar" el 50% de las neuronas para que no esté demasiado ajustado. No quiero que encuentre un único camino para "perros" sino que encuentre varios.
cnn.add(Dense(clases, activation = 'softmax'))

cnn.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=lr), metrics=['accuracy'])

cnn.fit_generator(imagen_entrenamiento, steps_per_epoch=pasos, epochs=epocas, validation_data=imagen_validacion, validation_steps=pasos_validacion)

dir = r'C:\Users\JOSEA\Downloads\data\modelos'

if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.mkdir(dir)
cnn.save(r'C:\Users\JOSEA\Downloads\data\modelos\modelo.h5')
cnn.save_weights(r'C:\Users\JOSEA\Downloads\data\modelos\pesos.h5')
```

THIS IS THE CALIDATION CODE (IT DOESNT COMPILE)

ERROR ON THE BOTTOM

```py
import os
import sys
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from keras.models import load_model

longitud, altura = 150, 150
modelo=r'C:\Users\JOSEA\Downloads\data\modelos\modelo.h5'
pesos=r'C:\Users\JOSEA\Downloads\data\modelos\pesos.h5'
cnn = load_model(modelo)
cnn.load_weights(pesos)

def predict(file):
    x = load_img(file, target_size=(longitud, altura))                           # Le paso a la x nuestro valor de longitud y altura de la imagen.
    x = img_to_array(x)                                                          # Convierto la imagen en un array de valores.
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)                                                # En el eje 0 (primera dimensión del array) quiero que me añada otra dimensión para procesar la imagen sin problema.
    arreglo = cnn.predict(x)                 ## [[1, 0, 0]]                      # Llamo a la red neuronal para haga una predicción y nos da un array de dos dimensiones tal que #[[1, 0, 0]] de la que solo se va a tomar el 1 como acierto.
    resultado = arreglo[0]                   ## [[0, 0, 1]]                      # Solo me interesa la primera dimensión como resultado.
    respuesta = np.argmax(resultado)         ## 2                                # Va a tomar como output la posición en el vector del valor mas alto.
    if respuesta == 0:
        print('perro')
    if respuesta == 1:
        print('gato')
    return respuesta

predict(r'C:\Users\JOSEA\Downloads\data\Extra_Dataset\cat.1440')
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\JOSEA\Anaconda3\envs\Ajedrez\python.exe C:/Users/JOSEA/PycharmProjects/Image_Classifier_TF/predicciones.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/JOSEA/PycharmProjects/Image_Classifier_TF/predicciones.py", line 12, in <module>
    cnn = load_model(modelo)
  File "C:\Users\JOSEA\Anaconda3\envs\Ajedrez\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 419, in load_model
    model = _deserialize_model(f, custom_objects, compile)
  File "C:\Users\JOSEA\Anaconda3\envs\Ajedrez\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 225, in _deserialize_model
    model = model_from_config(model_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\Users\JOSEA\Anaconda3\envs\Ajedrez\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py", line 458, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\Users\JOSEA\Anaconda3\envs\Ajedrez\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "C:\Users\JOSEA\Anaconda3\envs\Ajedrez\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 145, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "C:\Users\JOSEA\Anaconda3\envs\Ajedrez\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\sequential.py", line 300, in from_config
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "C:\Users\JOSEA\Anaconda3\envs\Ajedrez\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\__init__.py", line 55, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "C:\Users\JOSEA\Anaconda3\envs\Ajedrez\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 147, in deserialize_keras_object
    return cls.from_config(config['config'])
  File "C:\Users\JOSEA\Anaconda3\envs\Ajedrez\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1109, in from_config
    return cls(**config)
  File "C:\Users\JOSEA\Anaconda3\envs\Ajedrez\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\JOSEA\Anaconda3\envs\Ajedrez\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 490, in __init__
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\JOSEA\Anaconda3\envs\Ajedrez\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 117, in __init__
    self.kernel_initializer = initializers.get(kernel_initializer)
  File "C:\Users\JOSEA\Anaconda3\envs\Ajedrez\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers.py", line 508, in get
    return deserialize(identifier)
  File "C:\Users\JOSEA\Anaconda3\envs\Ajedrez\lib\site-packages\keras\initializers.py", line 503, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='initializer')
  File "C:\Users\JOSEA\Anaconda3\envs\Ajedrez\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 138, in deserialize_keras_object
    ': ' + class_name)
ValueError: Unknown initializer: GlorotUniform

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Hi it might be this issue https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/798

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing `keras` and `tf.keras` by training your model using `tf.keras` and then loading it in `keras`. This won't work because both frameworks are not compatible in that way.

Choose one implementation and use it completely, do not mix them.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
from keras.models import load_model
```

To:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```

That works for me. You can find additional information [here](https://github.com/puigalex/AMP-Tech/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed).